# How to schedule emails using MailJet 3.1?

Tags: php, email, curl, schedule, mailjet

I'm currently using MailJet 3.1 API to allow a client to send the same template email out to all subscribers when they hit submit on my form (information sent with MailJet using curl + PHP).

My dilemma is thus: my client needs to be able to schedule when this email is sent out. I need to allow them to choose a date and time in the form and then use MailJet 3.1 to schedule this accurately.

I've searched and searched and can find little to no information on scheduling in the new 3.1 API documentation - **can anyone else with more MailJet experience tell me if scheduling can in fact be done through MailJet 3.1** or do I have to use a third-party program in conjuction with MailJet (and if so, which one)?

[*Everything is set up - all I need to find is the parameter for the MailJet call to schedule the template emails.]

Comment: I am not experienced with MailJet, so take this for what you will, but it looks like the v3.1 label applies only to the mailjet send api, which would be used for transactional email only. Are you looking to schedule a newsletter? Perhaps [this is what you want](https://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/newsletter-schedule/#tab-Create) instead?

Comment: Thanks Marty! I gave the campaign/newsletter functionality that you pointed out a go over the Christmas break, though ultimately my team and I decided that the final solution to the problem was to simply use cronjobs on the server to give us more control over the scheduling.